# Keyboard For UITextView Remains Visible After Dismissing It - Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uikeyboard, resignfirstresponder

I have a view with many input fields. All of them are `UITextField`s expect for the one at the very bottom, which is a `UITextView`.

For some reason when I tap the screen to call `view.endEditing()` to dismiss the keyboard from the `UITextView`, sometimes the keyboard will stay up, and I'll have to tap the screen a second time to get it to dismiss. This issue never happens on `UITextField`s though.

I also get this error message:

[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7f95cf10ec70, UIInputSetHostView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: you can try to add this line `textview.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: Mb problem is call `textview.resignFirstResponder()` try to call `self.resignFirstResponder()` where `self` is UIViewController or root UIView

Comment: @arts That still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @Alastar I've tried that as well and the same problem persists

Comment: can you provide some code?